# Convert object to JSON String with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I`m working on an application that communicates with the server, and send data to a website, respectively, receives data from that website. 
The data is about 5 timetable that are optional.

For e.g. if 3 timetable are set, and I want to deselect one of those, it should send to website only 2 timetable. Here is a problem.

I analyse my code, and I concluded that the problem is in the method that Convert Object to JSON String.

Here is the code:

```
public class PriorityResponse {

    @JsonProperty("priority1")
    public Priority priorityOne;
    @JsonProperty("priority2")
    public Priority priorityTwo;
    @JsonProperty("priority3")
    public Priority priorityThree;
    @JsonProperty("priority4")
    public Priority priorityFour;
    @JsonProperty("priority5")
    public Priority priorityFive;

    public Priority getPriorityOne() {
        return priorityOne;
    }

    public Priority getPriorityTwo() {
        return priorityTwo;
    }

    public Priority getPriorityThree() {
        return priorityThree;
    }

    public Priority getPriorityFour() {
        return priorityFour;
    }

    public Priority getPriorityFive() {
        return priorityFive;
    }
   public String toJsonObject(){

         String jsonInString = "";
         ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
       //Object to JSON in String
         try {
             jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
         } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

         return jsonInString;
     }
}
```

At this line

```
jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
```

the string is null, but when return jsonInString, is sending 3 timetable, not 2. 
If I make other changes, it sending correct data, the problem is only when I want to deselect one or more timetable.

The output should be like this when I deselect Priority4:

```
{"priority5":{"number":null,"timeOut":null,"timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":false,"op":true},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":true,"sun":true,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}},"priority4":{"number":null,"timeOut":null,"timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":false,"op":true},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":true,"sun":true,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}},"priority1":{"number":"1234561231","timeOut":"9","timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":false,"op":true},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":false,"sun":false,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}},"priority3":{"number":"21515211545","timeOut":"","timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":true,"op":false},"fri":false,"mon":true,"sat":false,"sun":false,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":false}},"priority2":{"number":"789123156421","timeOut":"","timeTable":{"time":{"fh":"04","fm":"02","th":"13","tm":"07","cl":false,"op":false},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":true,"sun":true,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}}}
```

but, it seems that, the JSON string does not refresh when I deselect one priority, because is sent that same priority that I get initial. 
Here is what is sent:

```
{"priority5":{"number":null,"timeOut":null,"timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":false,"op":true},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":true,"sun":true,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}},"priority4":{"number":"12233456545","timeOut":"6","timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":false,"op":true},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":false,"sun":false,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}},"priority1":{"number":"1234561231","timeOut":"9","timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":false,"op":true},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":false,"sun":false,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}},"priority3":{"number":"21515211545","timeOut":"5","timeTable":{"time":{"fh":null,"fm":null,"th":null,"tm":null,"cl":true,"op":false},"fri":false,"mon":true,"sat":false,"sun":false,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":false}},"priority2":{"number":"789123156421","timeOut":"5","timeTable":{"time":{"fh":"04","fm":"02","th":"13","tm":"07","cl":false,"op":false},"fri":true,"mon":true,"sat":true,"sun":true,"thu":true,"tue":true,"wed":true}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use com.google.gson.Gson If any attribute is null the parser is

```
String jsonInString = new Gson().toJson(yourObject);
```

results:

```
{
 "priorityOne":{},
 "priorityTwo":{},
  ...
}
```

Comment: It would appear that the question is trying to use Jackson. Please respect that intent.

Answer (score 0):

Does setting the serializationInclusion to NON_NULL give you what you want?

```
public String toJsonObject() throws IOException{

     String jsonInString = "";
     ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
   //Object to JSON in String
     try {
         // Will only include non null objects
         mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_NULL);
         jsonInString = mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
     } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }

     return jsonInString;
 }
```

Comment: Unfortunately I receive the same result. The problem persist even if I use Inclusion.NON_NULL.

Comment: Hey:<br>Can you list out exactly what you want to see in your output? And what the state of each of the 5 "Priority" instances in your "PriorityResponse" object.

Comment: Explain what you mean by "deselect".. It seems like you think you are making the attribute "Priority4" null, but you aren't really...